# Win32com.client.dispatch Python call Equivalent in C or C++

Tags: python, c++, c

I have the following python code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import time 

ie = Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = 1
ie.Navigate("https://www.google.com")

while ie.ReadyState !=4:
    time.sleep(1)

result = ie.document.body.innerHTML
```

What would be the equivalent of `win32com.client.Dispatch` in C or C++?

Comment: Not sure it is what you are looking for, but you may have a look at boost::asio, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706852/using-boost-asio-to-get-web-page

Comment: No, my problem is not sending an HTTP request 
I want to automate internet explorer tasks using win32com.client.Dispatch

Answer (score 0):

I find my Answer in here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879041/how-to-interact-with-internet-explorer-c][1]

my code shulde be following this :

```
#include <comutil.h>    // _variant_t
#include <mshtml.h>     // IHTMLDocument and IHTMLElement
#include <exdisp.h>     // IWebBrowser2
#include <atlbase.h>    // CComPtr
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Make sure we link in the support library!
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")


// Load a webpage
HRESULT LoadWebpage(
    const CComBSTR& webpageURL,
    CComPtr<IWebBrowser2>& browser,
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2>& document)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    VARIANT empty;

    VariantInit(&empty);

    // Navigate to the specifed webpage
    hr = browser->Navigate(webpageURL, &empty, &empty, &empty, &empty);

    //  Wait for the load.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        READYSTATE state;

        while(SUCCEEDED(hr = browser->get_ReadyState(&state)))
        {
            if(state == READYSTATE_COMPLETE) break;
        }
    }

    // The browser now has a document object. Grab it.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CComPtr<IDispatch> dispatch;

        hr = browser->get_Document(&dispatch);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && dispatch != NULL)
        {
            hr = dispatch.QueryInterface<IHTMLDocument2>(&document);
        }
        else
        {
            hr = E_FAIL;
        }
    }

    return hr;
}


void CrawlWebsite(const CComBSTR& webpage, std::vector<std::wstring>& urlList)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    // Create a browser object
    CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> browser;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_InternetExplorer,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_SERVER,
        IID_IWebBrowser2,
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(&browser));

    // Grab a web page
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> document;
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Make sure these two items are scoped so CoUninitialize doesn't gump
        // us up.
        hr = LoadWebpage(webpage, browser, document);
    }

    // Grab all the anchors!
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CComPtr<IHTMLElementCollection> urls;
        long count = 0;

        hr = document->get_all(&urls);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = urls->get_length(&count);
        }

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            for(long i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                CComPtr<IDispatch>  element;
                CComPtr<IHTMLAnchorElement> anchor;

                // Get an IDispatch interface for the next option.
                _variant_t index = i;
                hr = urls->item( index, index, &element);
                if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = element->QueryInterface(
                        IID_IHTMLAnchorElement, 
                        reinterpret_cast<void **>(&anchor));
                }

                if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && anchor != NULL)
                {
                    CComBSTR    url;
                    hr = anchor->get_href(&url);
                    if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && url != NULL)
                    {
                        urlList.push_back(std::wstring(url));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    std::vector<std::wstring>   urls;

    CComBSTR webpage(L"http://cppreference.com");


    CrawlWebsite(webpage, urls);
    for(std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator it = urls.begin();
        it != urls.end();
        ++it)
    {
        std::wcout << "URL: " << *it << std::endl;

    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```